# Chave do meu JSON inacessível para validação em Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, array, node.js, knex.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma API em Node.js e Knex.js, porém me deparei com um problema, o array que o Knex retorna na promessa tem um JSON dentro e é numérico que precisa ser validado. Contudo, a chave é estranha e não é possível acessar o seu valor, então não consigo fazer uma resposta correta.

Código:

```
async dateValidator(request, response){
    const {loja, data} = request.body;
    const queryCountData = conection('agendamentos').count("data").where({"data": data, 'loja': loja});
    queryCountData.then(resp => {
        if(resp[0].count >= 13){
        response.status(401).json(resp);
        }
        if(resp < 13){
            response.status(201).json(resp);
        }
    }); 
}
```

O JSON resultante:

```
[
  {
    "count(data)": 13
  }
]
```

A chave do objeto é `count(data)`. Como faço pra acessar esse objeto em JavaScript, sendo que tem parênteses (`()`) dentro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação do Knex](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-count), você pode passar uma opção `as` para mudar o nome do campo `count(data)`:

```js
.count('data', { as: 'data' })
```

A partir daí a chave dos objetos retornados para esse campo será `data`, e não mais `` count(`data`) ``:

```
resp[0].count // OK
```

A título de curiosidade, essa chave **não é "inacessível"**. Em casos como esse, a [notação de colchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_colchete) deve ser utilizada para o acesso, uma vez que parênteses não são identificadores válidos em JavaScript:

```
resp[0]['count(data)'] // OK
```

Veja que é possível acessar chaves com qualquer tipo de caractere através dessa notação:

```js
const strangeObject = {
  'count(data)': 10,
  '': 20
};

console.log(strangeObject['count(data)']); // 10
console.log(strangeObject['']); // 20
```

Comment: eu tinha me esquecido totalmente da opção "as" eu to pegando agora o knex, eu lidava com sql direto e era altomatico isso ja, mas com o knex é tudo novo

Comment: cara obrigado de verdade